# Pandas melt multiple groups into single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose, melt

Original DataFrame:

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| ID |  var1hrs |  var2hrs |  ind1var |  ind2var |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  1 |       55 |       45 |      123 |      456 |
|  2 |       48 |       60 |      331 |      222 |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Target DataFrame:

```
+----+------------+------+------+
| ID |    type    |  hrs |  ind |
+----+------------+------+------+
|  1 |  primary   |   55 |  123 |
|  1 |  secondary |   45 |  456 |
|  2 |  primary   |   48 |  331 |
|  2 |  secondary |   60 |  222 |
+----+------------+------+------+
```

How would I go about melting multiple groups of variables into a single label column? The "1" in the variable names indicate type = "primary" and "2" indicates type = "secondary".

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Comments inlined)

```
# set ID as the index and sort columns
df = df.set_index('ID').sort_index(axis=1)

# extract primary columns
prim = df.filter(like='1')
prim.columns = ['ind', 'vars']
# extract secondary columns 
sec = df.filter(like='2')
sec.columns = ['ind', 'vars']

# concatenation + housekeeping
v = (pd.concat([prim, sec], keys=['primary', 'secondary'])
       .swaplevel(0, 1)
       .rename_axis(['ID', 'type'])
       .reset_index()
)

print(v)
   ID       type  ind  vars
0   1    primary  123    55
1   2    primary  331    48
2   1  secondary  456    45
3   2  secondary  222    60
```

This is more or less one efficient way of doing it, even if the steps are a bit involved.

Answer (score 5):

After modify the columns' name, we can using `wide_to_long`

```
df.columns=df.columns.str[:4]
s=pd.wide_to_long(df,['var','ind'],i='ID',j='type').reset_index()
s=s.assign(type=s.type.map({'1':'primary','2':'secondary'})).sort_values('ID')
s

   ID       type  var  ind
0   1    primary   55  123
2   1  secondary   45  456
1   2    primary   48  331
3   2  secondary   60  222
```

Comment: I am surprised by how bad the documentation is for these functions wide_to_long... it seems useful.

Comment: @coldspeed Agree ! the explanation is unclear, I struggle with `suffix` for a long time

Comment: I also had trouble figuring out how to use that function! What would you do if "ind1var and "ind2var" were named "var1ind" and "var2ind" instead? Slicing all the columns with [:4] would then result in duplicate column names.

Comment: @jerbear this is tough question `pd.wide_to_long(df,['var1','var2'],i='ID',j='drop',suffix='\w+').unstack(-2).T
` but you can do this